# LinkedIn Import to Careers 2.0 only displaying partial data

Tags: support, jobs

I did the import from Careers 2.0 of my LinkedIn data and all went well.  Then I updated a bunch of items in LinkedIn.  Now the import in Careers doesn't seem to be picking up the new data at all.  Is there a time delay between updating LinkedIn and when it becomes available to external services?  Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is just a delay. I just clicked the Import link again from within Careers, and it displayed/imported all the new data.  So roughly 2 hour delay for some reason.